# Export GCP Datastore schema for collection

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

Is there a way to export the schema of a namespace + kind for entities in datastore? I want to store this to be able to track the schema of the added data to datastore, if we will change it in the future.
Or do I have to handle this manually?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#exporting_specific_kinds_or_namespaces), you can use the below command to export a specific kind and/or namespaces, provide an entity filter with values for kinds and namespace IDs.

```
gcloud datastore export --kinds="KIND1,KIND2" --namespaces="(default),NAMESPACE2" gs://bucket-name --async
```